# how to save filenames that have a forward slash in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

The `xdmp:save()` couldn't save the XML file names that have forward slash.  Is there a way to keep the file names having special characters?  I appreciate any help you can provide.

```
"AA-12-0002/1",
"AB-13-0002/1"
```

Comment: A bit more info would help.. Operating system? Filesystem?  Error Message? Is it OK to  actually create directories for each level of slashes?

Answer (score 1):

[You can't](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/359817/5428).

For a filesystem path, slashes denote a directory. When saving the URIs above, you would have a filename of `1` inside of the directory `AA-12-0002` and `AB-13-0002`.